# number of days between march and april

Tags: objective-c, xcode

in objective-C, i am calculating the number of days between 2 dates, all is fine, except between March and April,

see result below:

```
date1: 2015-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
date2: 2015-03-28 22:00:00 +0000
number of days: -3

date1: 2015-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
date2: 2015-03-29 22:00:00 +0000
number of days: -1


date1: 2015-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
date2: 2015-03-30 22:00:00 +0000
number of days: 0


date1: 2015-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
date2: 2015-03-31 22:00:00 +0000
number of days: 0
```

the code used is:

```
components = [self.calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                      fromDate:date1
                                                        toDate:date2
options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
```

Comment: does it account for daylight savings and 29th february?

Comment: what is daylight saving? and shouldn't 29th feb be calculated automatically?

Comment: 1. google it. 2. I don't know but maybe it isn't.

Comment: The *NSDate* class (similar to Java's *Date* class) has been named very poorly as it does not represent a date. Instead, it represents a point in time, which – at all times – is associated with at least two calendar dates (depending on the calendar and time zone context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the hour of the date at 12 PM, and that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country Some countries start it by the last week of march.

Apparently you're calendar object is aware of the daylight savings time and it actually counts the hour you're moving your clock forward to.

This is actually working fine, as the number of days as 24 hour units are computed correctly.

Comment: thank you, so what is the solution? i need an accurate number of days